# Windows Server: Multiple remote desktop user logins but the same setup (programs, files, shortcuts etc.)

Tags: remote-desktop, user-accounts, user-profiles, windows-server

At the moment we are remote desktoping into a windows server with the same login credentials to be able to use the same setup (programs, files, shortcuts etc.)

But for security purpose we want to change this procedure, so each user has different logins. We still want to keep the same setup across different logins, so each user does not have to setup all the programs that is needed on the server, and all shortcuts for files, folders or programs.

Is it possible to make this setup and how is it done?

Comment: is the rdp server inside a domain? are the logins the same as the users would use to login to their local machine?

Comment: @SimonS Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating new user accounts with default desktop settings, favorites, and Start menu,
you could use the default user profile of Windows.

In Windows 10 this profile is located in the directory `C:\Users\Default`.

The contents of this default user profile are provided to every new user
account on the system. When a new user profile is created, these default
settings and files will be copied to the new user's profile directory.

By placing your shortcuts for files, folders and programs in the
default user folder, they will copied to every new local account that
you will in the future create on the server.

---

If you really like that all your users share the very same desktop
and Start menu, this will mean that any change by one user will propagate
to all of them.

If you still wish all user logins to and up with one user profile,
set all their profile paths to the same path.

The profile path of any user account can be found in the registry under
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
in the item named `ProfileImagePath` whose value will be
`C:\Users\user-name`.

[[image] click for a larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1YAw.jpg)

The keys use the account's System ID (SID). If the user cannot easily
be identified by the value of `ProfileImagePath`,
to convert the marked SID to the current user account name, enter in cmd the command:

```
wmic useraccount where sid='S-1-3-12-12451234567-1234567890-1234567-1434' get name
```

You will need to modify the permissions of the shared folder so that
all users could access these folders. If you don't wish them to be able
to change these folders, don't give them write permissions to some
sub-folders
(it would be strange for users not to be in control of their
desktop or have access to documents of other  users).

---

Another alternative is to modify for the user the
settings under registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`, such as `Desktop` and `Start Menu`.

Comment: Yes, but you will have to maintain this default profile. I want it to behave as if you only had one profile user. My question should probably just have been: How to login to a single shared user with different credentials.

Comment: I have added some possibilities, although none of them is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Any programs installed as an Administrator (to `C:\Program Files\ProgramName\` for example) are generally going to be available for all users. Settings saved to the install folder should also be identical for all users, e.g: `C:\Program Files\ProgramName\`.

Programs like to keep **user-specific** settings in two main areas:

- Hidden appdata folder: `C:\Users\$username\Appdata\`
- The user registry: `HKEY_USERS\S-1-2-3-Very-long-unique-ID\SOFTWARE\`

Be aware that not all software follows best practices here - we have some that keep settings in `C:\CustomFolder`, `C:\Users\$username\CustomFolder`, etc. You will have to do some investigation.

Like [@harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672/harrymc) says, these can generally by copied to the Default user profile folder and registry (`HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\`).

If you have any examples of settings you'd like to keep or are having trouble finding, add them to your question and we can suggest where to look.

**Also: Please verify that your software's licensing allows you to use it this way!** This can be an unfortunate surprise...

Comment: Yes, but you will have to maintain this default profile. I want it to behave as if you only had one profile user. My question should probably just have been: How to login to a single shared user with different credentials.

Comment: @Jogge If you want the settings to update for all users, you'll have to change where they're stored to a location all users can write to (e.g. `C:\MyAppSettings\`). If you can't do it in the application, you can softlink files to a shared location instead. Be careful of how you handle multiple people logged in at once though. If that wouldn't work, can you add an example of what you want to see?